# checking whether azure resource has a valid name from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet

How to do these check via powershell. I have some resources like

1. FunctionApp
2. FunctionAppService
3. EventHub Namespace
4. Storage Account
5. ServiceBus

[image]

I am able to verify the EventHub Namespace and Storage account via built-in cmdlets available. like **Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability** and **Test-AzureRmEventHubName**, but I cannot achieve any custom logic that can check if the name of the entered resource is valid. Some users tend to provide name's to resources that are most commonly used, so I have partially avoided this by appending some unique characters to the resources, but it will be good to have cmdlets or such for other types of resources too.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I thnk you are looking for [Test-AzureName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/test-azurename?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) - allows you to check exactly what you are looking for.

However, this does not seem to be [available in Resource-Manger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/489) version of Azure Powershell, so you might need to load classic Azure account via

```
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId "<YourSubId>"
```

And also you'll need to have [classic Azure PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/5.1.1) installed as well.

Disclaimer: I've not used this cmdlet myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

The command `Test-AzureName` only works for classic Azure resource.

For a function web app name, the valid characters are `a-z`, `0-9`, and `-`, uppercase letters are not allowed. So you could name your web app as `coffee-functionapp`.

More information about this you could check this [link:Naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions).

Based on my knowledge, there is no API could check resource name valid, if you really need this, you could give a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager) to Azure.

Comment: Hi, please let me know if you need more future help.